# ExecutorService.invokeAll and shutdown

Tags: java, concurrency, executor

So I have some Callable tasks, **sensitive to interruptions**, which I submit to the ExecutorService using invokeAll. After 5 seconds from another method I call executorService.shutdownNow after which I call the awaitTermination, which returns true, so all seems good. The problem is the executor never terminates.

**Due to logging I know that each one of my tasks finished.**
nevertheless the invokeAll still blocks on f.get when i is equal to the number of threads of the executor:

**The following code is obtained from AbstractExecutorService** + some logging.

```
        @Override
    public <T> List<Future<T>> invokeAll(Collection<? extends Callable<T>> tasks) throws InterruptedException {
        if (tasks == null) throw new NullPointerException();
        ArrayList<Future<T>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<T>>(tasks.size());
        boolean done = false;
        try {
            List<Callable<T>> list = new ArrayList<Callable<T>>();
            for (Callable<T> t : tasks) {
                list.add(t);
                RunnableFuture<T> f = newTaskFor(t);
                futures.add(f);
                execute(f);
            }
            for (int i = 0, size = futures.size(); i < size; i++) {
                Future<T> f = futures.get(i);
                if (!f.isDone()) {
                    log.info("Future %s is not done!. Task %s", i, list.get(i));
                    try {
                        log.info("Get from future %s", i);
                        // NEXT LINE BLOCKS FOR i= NUMBER OF THREADS
                        f.get();
                        log.info("Got result from future %s", i);
                    } catch (CancellationException ignore) {
                    } catch (ExecutionException ignore) {
                    }
                }
            }
            log.info("Obtained all!");
            done = true;
            return futures;
        } finally {
            if (!done) for (int i = 0, size = futures.size(); i < size; i++)
                futures.get(i).cancel(true);
        }
    }
```

Am I not suppose to use invokeAll with shutdown? I guess not, after all they are in the same class. Why does it get blocked, only when i= the number of threads of the executor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, you're not suppose to use invokeAll with shutdown**. At least this is what I understand, correct me if I'm wrong.

- The shutdownNow method:

> ```
> public List<Runnable> shutdownNow() {
> ...
>         checkShutdownAccess();
>         advanceRunState(STOP);
>         interruptWorkers();
>         tasks = drainQueue();
> ...
> }
> ```

The only thing is does is interrupt working threads and remove the rest of the runnables from the working queue, see drainQueue. **ShutdownNow/Shutdown does not modify the futures in our invokeAll method**

So what happens in my case is that for an Executor with N threads, I invoke 300 jobs, each of them take more than 1 minute, after 5 seconds I cancel (interrupt working threads), N threads are interrupted (**0 to N-1**). What happens with the rest of the futures? **Nothing**, the next call to f.get() (see corresponding line in the question)  will block and you're stuck there. This explains why I'm always blocked on i = Number of threads.